# Create Index Based on Query In MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a query and I want to create an index based on a query In MySQL work bench not in MSSQL Server.

In MSSQL server we have an option to find the missing index (Using Execution Plan Ctrl+L) of a query then we will create that index but i am unable to do the same thing in MySQL Work Bench.

Comment: Create index on relational columns... Where a.id = b.id_a

Comment: in MySQL it's `EXPLAIN <query>` to get a Execution Plan

Comment: 1) filter condition in the query is not static it will change dynamically so we can't predict the relational columns @Roy

Comment: EXPLAIN <query> is also tried but it is not useful to me @RaymondNijland

Comment: *"EXPLAIN <query> is also tried but it is not useful to me"* that is because you don't understand the output most likely or how you to interpreted that see [EXPLAIN Output Format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html)

Comment: *"In MSSQL server we have an option to find the missing index (Using Execution Plan Ctrl+L) of a query then we will create that index but i am unable to do the same thing in MySQL Work Bench."* Short answer there isn't a automatic option in MySQL..

Comment: Show me the query plus the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) involved; I'll give you the optimal index(es).  Or you can use my cheatsheet: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql